# How to get number of seconds between two button clicks

Tags: c#

I have two buttons. Start and Stop.

I need when I press start, count the time till I press stop and send how many second and minutes on message box.

I start like this

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //start
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //end
    DateTime end = DateTime.Now;

    MessageBox.Show(end-now);
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx), it is the most accurate.

Here's an example:

```
static Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();


private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sw.Start();
}

private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sw.Stop();

    TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;

    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", 
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);

    MessageBox.Show("Elapsed time = " + elapsedTime);
}
```

It is fully working and tested but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post images.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
DateTime start;
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //start
    start = DateTime.Now;
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //end            
    TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - start;
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} minutes and {1} seconds", 
                    Math.Floor(ts.TotalMinutes), ts.Seconds));
}
```

This gives result like this.

[image]

Comment: You would not use `Total Seconds`, you need just [`Seconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.seconds.aspx). If you use `TotalSeconds` and you waited 61 seconds it would output `1 minutes and 61 seconds`

Comment: Now you have the oppiste problem, By changing `TotalMinutes` to `Minutes` if you waited 1 hour it would say `0 minutes and 0 seconds`

Comment: ineed only total of mint and total of seconds to know the cost

Comment: @Homam: Edit for what?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [stopwatch class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Example from msdn:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
Thread.Sleep(10000);
stopWatch.Stop();
// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

// Format and display the TimeSpan value. 
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
    ts.Milliseconds / 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other answers, use the `Stopwatch` class. Just make sure that both buttons have access to the same stopwatch.

```
public class ThisClass{
  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

  private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    sw.start();//or sw.Restart()
  }

  private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //stop
    sw.Stop();
    int numSeconds=sw.ElapsedSeconds;//or other members of sw
  }

}//end class
```

It is important that the `Stopwatch` object be in the same namespace/scope as the button press functions so that they can both manipulate the same `Stopwatch` object.